# ngrok does not load NodeJS app from outside (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: node.js, ngrok

ngrok is a program with which you can make a local tunnel, it generates a temporary domain for you so you can redirect people to your local content, and also use https via localhost.
https://ngrok.com/

localtunnel is just another alternative.

So I have set up either ngrok and a localtunnel but both show a white page with only the HTML loading and not css or js when loaded outside of my network (with data plan for example)

The problem is nothing gives an error, the only thing I can see is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when using a hotspot.

Everything works within my own network.

I have tried turning off the firewall already but it seems to make no difference, also tried looking with the chrome remote debugger but it just disconnects when I load the url.

Thing is when I go to https:// on the ngrok url I get a bunch of mixed content errors, but not when I go to http. Seem illogical to me that it would default to http when using a https link... all of my script/style tags are relative paths.

Anyway so far this is only thing that I can figure out, any ideas on what might cause this?

So it's either

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

or

```
Blocked loading mixed active content
```

or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I go it working now by changing the base href.

```
<base href="http://yoururl.ngrok.io">
```

And also changing some paths in my config to either /app/ or ../ respectively, but most of these were already set correctly and all I did was revert them after changing the base url.

As far I understand now the problems only really start to occur when connecting to the url through a data plan and not wifi.

Some random image paths in css/js will not load, and it also appears to behave differently on Firefox and Chrome for some reason.

Problem is I cannot keep testing this indefinitely as data will obviously run out some time and I have no reliable way of debugging the console errors on mobile...

In conclusion it works on a "normal" connection now (ie Wifi/Cable) but not on data.